# call other layout or xml file in frame of a tab in android

Tags: android, xml, layout

Inside frame of my tab i am calling an activity having first.xml xml file. Inside this i have two different layout. I have one more xml file graph.xml. Right now i am passing my intent to another activity where i have setcontentview of graph.xml but what i want now is to display this graph inside my first.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"          
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"          
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearfullview" android:layout_height="400sp" android:background="@drawable/background_full_view" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/> 

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="180sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_marginTop="20sp">              
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                  

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"                  
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"                  
        android:paddingRight="2dp"                  
        android:paddingTop="4dp" 
        android:gravity="bottom"                 
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">                    
        <com.widget.WheelView 
        android:id="@+id/segment"                  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                  
        android:layout_width="100dp"/>                            
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout> 

        </RelativeLayout>
```

I want to have graph.xml layout inside linearfullview linear layout. please suggest

Comment: What have you tried?  You should probably post your code so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: You want to show Activity inside Activity in a single Tab?

Comment: LayoutInflater lInflator2 = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      RelativeLayout linearLayout2 = (RelativeLayout) lInflator2.inflate(R.layout.forecast, null); 
      LinearLayout ly = (LinearLayout) linearLayout2.findViewById(R.id.linearfullview);
      LayoutInflater lInflator = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) lInflator.inflate(R.layout.graph_layout, null); 
      ly.addView(linearLayout);
      setContentView(ly);

Comment: @LalitPoptani I want to display graph_layout.xml inside linearfulview layout i have defined in my above xml file

Comment: You can come to casual chat room and explain me there if you can come..

Comment: I think I get what he is trying to do as I have the same issue. Basically he wants to call one XML layout from within another XML layout. In my case, I have a TabHost with 4 tabs and each tab needs a rather long/involved form. Without being able to call another XML from within the TabHost XML it would make for one seriously massive and unwieldy single XML layout. Would love to get some help on how to accomplish this in a more modular XML way.